# Why doesn't the memory footprint of this program increase?

Tags: c

I am in a scratchbox cross compile environment and have this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int * ptr;
    int i=0;

    while(1)
    {
        ptr = (int*)malloc( 10485760 * sizeof(int) );

        if(ptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not malloc\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Malloc done\n");
            for (i = 0 ; i <= 10485759 ; i++)
            {
                ptr[i] = i ;
            }
            sleep (5);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the binary and do

```
ps -p pid -o cmd,rss,%mem
```

I do not see any increase in the memory footprint of the process. Why is that?

Comment: because the memory is all allocated at once in the beginning?

Comment: @arasmussen Inside a `while` loop.

Comment: Maybe the compiler sees that you no longer have a handle on that pointer (because you over write ptr every time) and is cleaning up after it for you? Or maybe it's taking a long time to run ten million iterations?

Comment: I see increasing memory footprint here (gcc-4.5.1, 64-bit linux).

Comment: @arasmussen that won't be it because (a) the compiler doesn't see run time behavior of the program, and (b) there's no garbage collection in C.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is the amount of increase are you seeing?

Comment: Tell us what OS and compiler?

Comment: 40 meg per 5 seconds, as expected.

Comment: @CharlieMartin I am in a scratchbox cross compile environment. Running it as an ARM binary.

Comment: It's possible your kernel was compiled with page deduplication, as I understand it that's a big win for systems hosting multiple vm's.  Try `r=open("/dev/urandom",O_RDONLY); /* then in the loop ... */ read(r,ptr, 10485760 *sizeof*ptr);`, that should fix its little red wagon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably built very optimized.

On most modern systems gcc knows that malloc returns a non-aliased pointer. That is to say, it will never return the same pointer twice and it will never return a pointer you have saved 'live' somewhere else.

I find this very very hard to imagine, but it is possible that malloc is being called once and its return value being used over and over.  The reasons being:

It knows your memory is a dead store. ie: you write to it, but it never gets read from. The pointer is known to not be aliased so it hasn't escaped to be read from somewhere else, and it isn't marked volatile.  Your for loop itself /could/ get thrown away.

At that point it could just use the same memory over and over.

Now here is why I find it hard to believe: Just how much does gcc know about malloc?  Malloc could have any kind of side effects like incrementing a global 'number of times called' to 'paints my room a random shade of blue'.   It seems really weird that it would drop the call and assume it to be side-effect-free.  Hell, 'malloc' could be implemented to return NULL every 100th call (maybe not quite to spec, but who is to say).

What it is NOT doing is freeing it on your behalf.   That goes beyond what it 'could' know and into the territory of 'doing things it's just not allowed to'.  You're allowed to leak memory, lame though it may be.

2 things would be useful here:
1) Compile environmenet: which os, compiler, and command line flags.

and 2) disassembly of the final binary.  (objdump or from the compiler)

Comment: _Just how much does gcc know about malloc?_ gcc is allowed to know Everything about `malloc()`, because the C Standard specifies the behaviour of that function.

Answer (score 2):

rss and %mem are both in terms of "physical memory being used by the process at the moment". It has plenty of opportunity to page stuff out. Try adding vsz. I bet that grows as you expect.

Comment: Bumping you up.  If you assume what I said below about the compiler being able to throw away the assignment loop as a dead store, this memory would be reserved but never committed and could loop until address space ran out; without ever actually committing a byte. :)

Answer (score -2):

Your compiler is helping you out by freeing the allocated memory (assuming that the optimized version of your code even gets around to doing the malloc) when it realizes that you aren't using it.  You might try printing out the value of the pointer (printf("0x%x", ptr);) - I suspect you'll be getting repeating values.  A more reliable check would write a known bitstring into memory, having already looked to see if the allocated memory already contains that string.  In other words, instead of writing i, write 0xdeadbeef0cabba6e over and over again, after checking to see if that bit pattern is already in the space you have allocated.

Comment: C isn't normally going to do that kind of garbage collection at run time.  But it's interesting to think about what a compiler *could* do.  None of `ptr[i]` is ever read from, so that assignment could be elided.  Then none of the memory allocated by `malloc` is used in any way, so in principal that could be elided (if we're satisfied that "amount of memory allocated" is not a correctness property that must be preserved).  However the first one is probably tricky with aliasing, and I'd be surprised if any C compiler in existence does the second one; not sure it's a valid transformation anyway.

Comment: I never suggested that there was any garbage collection going on whatsoever.  The C spec allows any optimization whatsoever under the sole condition that the final result has no functional difference from that defined by the C abstract machine definition.  (NOTE that we are not talking about a VM in the Java sense, but in the sense that the C spec defines an abstract machine as a mechanism for defining the behavior of compiled code.)  It would be well within the purview of the optimizer to eliminate the allocations from the above code entirely.

Comment: "Garbage Collection" is the process of making decisions - at runtime - about when unreferenced memory may be freed.  We are not talking about a runtime decision here, but a compile-time effect of noticing that the data allocated and written to is never used.